# How to make Angular ng-switch animate(enter/leave) in more than one way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation, ng-switch

I write an angular directive called 'cardViewer', which can show images inside it with animation.

When you press "prev" button, image slides left. When you press "next" button, image slides right.

I try to do this with `ng-switch`, which only supports `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` animation class. But I need two ways to enter(enter from left and right), two ways to leave(leave to left and right).

So I try `ng-class` to solve this problem. I hope it can add `toLeft` class before it switch, so it can apply specific css animation.

But it seems not working properly. When I press "next" button twice, it works fine. but when I press "next", then press "prev", new image enter in right direction, but old image leave in wrong direction.

My directive template:

```html
<h1>hahaha</h1>
  <div>
    <button ng-click='prev()'>prev</button>
    <button ng-click='next()'>next</button>
  </div>
<div>current Card Index: {{displayCard}}</div>

<div class="card-container" ng-switch="displayCard">
<img class="card"
   src="http://i.imgur.com/EJRdIcf.jpg" ng-switch-when="1" 
   ng-class="{'toLeft': toLeft, 'toRight': toRight}"/>
<img class="card"
   src="http://i.imgur.com/StaoX5y.jpg" ng-switch-when="2" 
   ng-class="{'toLeft': toLeft, 'toRight': toRight}"/>
<img class="card"
   src="http://i.imgur.com/eNcDvLE.jpg" ng-switch-when="3" 
   ng-class="{'toLeft': toLeft, 'toRight': toRight}"/>
</div>
```

directive:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .directive('cardViewer', function() {

  return {
    templateUrl: 'cardViewer.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.toLeft = false;
      scope.toRight = false;

      scope.displayCard = 1;

      //when press prev, card slide to left
      scope.prev = function() {
        scope.toLeft = true;
        scope.toRight = false;
        if (scope.displayCard == 1) {
          scope.displayCard = 3
        } else {
          scope.displayCard -= 1;
        }
      };

      //when press prev, card slide to right
      scope.next = function() {
        scope.toLeft = false;
        scope.toRight = true;

        if (scope.displayCard == 3) {
          scope.displayCard = 1
        } else {
          scope.displayCard += 1;
        }
      };
    }
  }
});
```

css:

```css
.card-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.card.ng-animate {
  transition: 1s linear all;
}

.card.ng-enter.toLeft {
  left: 100%;
}
.card.ng-enter-active.toLeft {
  left: 0;
}
.card.ng-leave.toLeft {
  left: 0;
}
.card.ng-leave-active.toLeft {
  left: -100%;
}

.card.ng-enter.toRight {
  left: -100%;
}

.card.ng-enter-active.toRight {
  left: 0;
}

.card.ng-leave.toRight {
  left: 0;
}

.card.ng-leave-active.toRight {
  left: 100%;
}
```

Here is my plunker: [cardViewer](http://plnkr.co/edit/AfMTUjm9VSc3CjB9AcgZ?p=preview)

What's wrong with my code? What's the right way to make ng-switch enter/leave in more than one way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `ngSwitch` is destroying the scope of the current image before `ngClass` has a chance to execute and change that image's class from `toRight` to `toLeft` (or vice versa) before the animation starts.

[ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) creates a new scope and executes at priority level 1200, while [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) executes at priority level 0.

To make it work, you just need to update your `next` and `prev` methods so they set the `displayCard` property in a `$timeout`, after `toLeft` and `toRight` are set, so `ngClass` has an opportunity to act on the new `toLeft`/`toRight` settings before `ngSwitch` destroys that scope.

So your `next` method, for example, would look like this:

```
scope.next = function() {
  scope.toLeft = false;
  scope.toRight = true;

  // need to do this in a $timeout so ngClass has 
  // chance to update the current image's class based 
  // on the new toLeft and toRight settings before
  // ngSwitch acts on the new displayCard setting
  // and destroys the current images's scope.
  $timeout(function () {
    if (scope.displayCard == 3) {
      scope.displayCard = 1
    } else {
      scope.displayCard += 1;
    }
  }, 0);
};
```

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/CIzygXvCMweT3RxP1HOY?p=preview) a fork your plunk showing it working. Open the console to see log messages for when `ngClass` adds your classes and `ngSwitch` destroys and creates the scopes.

I left your original "next" and "prev" buttons there and just added "next (fixed)" and "prev (fixed)" buttons so you can compare the log messages and see how, using the original buttons, `ngSwitch` destroys the scope before `ngClass` executes, while in the fixed versions `ngClass` executes before `ngSwitch` destroys the scope.